# jquery plugin options array, preventing array overwrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a plugin for jquery, and I have used a code like this to allow users to specify options for the plugin:

```
var settings = $.extend({
    url     : 'error.json',
    slotWidth   : 100,
    slotHeight  : 100,
    gridWidth   : 6,
    gridHeight  : 3,
    basketLayers    : 1,
    layerDirection  : "vertical",
    classNames  : {
            productPanelParent  : '.products-panel-parent',
            productPanelTabs    : '.products-panel-tabs',
            productPanelGroup   : '.products-panel-container',
            productPanel    : '.products-panel',
            productBasketParent : '.products-basket-parent',
            productBasketGroup  : '.products-basket-container',
            productBasket   : '.products-basket',
            productBasketMenu   : '.products-basket-menu',
            basketSlot      : '.basket-slot',
            basketSlotFull  : '.basket-slot-full',
            basketSlotHelper    : '.basket-slot-highlight',
            product     : '.product',
            resetBasket     : '.clearBasket',
            resetLayer      : '.clearLayer',
            viewLayer       : '.viewLayer'
          }
}, options);
```

The problem is that when I try to override one of the classNames, the whole array is written over with `null` values wherever a property wasn't specificed.

So for example, I'll do something like this:

```
$('#somediv').myPlugin({
    gridWidth : 4,
    gridHeight : 2,
    classNames : {
        productBasket : '.small_basket'
    }
});
```

And the `settings.classNames.productBasket` property will be the correct value, but everything is in settings.classNames will be null.

How do I get around this?
*(without writing a custom function to handle default values in the array?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) can be a boolean. If it's `true`, then the extension is "deep" (the merge is made recursively):

```
var settings = $.extend(true, defaults, options);
```

From the docs:

> The merge performed by `$.extend()` is not recursive by default; if a
>   property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be
>   completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second
>   object. The values are not merged... However, **by passing true for the
>   first function argument, objects will be recursively merged**.